# Get vector of column names depending on logicals of same dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, names

I have a named dataframe containig logicals with missings and I want to get a vector with the column names where values are `TRUE` (going down the rows and, if multiple `TRUE`s in one row, going from left to right). Here an example:

```
df <- data.frame(a= c(FALSE, NA, TRUE, TRUE),
                 b= c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, NA),
                 c= c(TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA))
df
#       a     b    c
# 1 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
# 2    NA FALSE TRUE
# 3  TRUE FALSE   NA
# 4  TRUE    NA   NA

expected <- c("b", "c", "c", "a", "a")
```

Going from first to last row we see `TRUE` in the first row. Here are multiple `TRUE`s, thus we go from left to right and get `"b"` and `"c"`. In second tow we get `"c"`, and so on.

How to do this (in an elegant way)?

Comment: Hey, please check my answer. If your data is large and efficiency is taken into account, my answer is faster than the accepted one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do in `base` R:

```
pos <- which(t(df) == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)
names(df)[pos[, "row"]]
[1] "b" "c" "c" "a" "a"
```

Comment: Nice! I just came up with `rep(names(df), nrow(df))[ifelse(is.na(unlist(t(df))), FALSE, unlist(t(df)))]` but find your answer much clearer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using `apply`

```
unlist(apply(df, 1, function(x){na.omit(names(df)[x])}))

[1] "b" "c" "c" "a" "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidyverse way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

vector <- df %>% 
  mutate(across(, ~case_when(.==TRUE ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}')) %>%
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ', ') %>% 
  separate_rows(New_Col) %>% 
  pull(New_Col)
```

Or:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(, ~case_when(.==TRUE ~ cur_column()))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  pull(value)
```

```
[1] "b" "c" "c" "a" "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::pmap`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pmap(df, ~ names(df)[c(...)] %>% na.omit) %>% unlist

#> [1] "b" "c" "c" "a" "a"
```

Comment: This one is a better `tidyverse` solution! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%%`(modulo) to identify the column indices.

```r
names(df)[(which(t(df)) - 1) %% ncol(df) + 1]

# [1] "b" "c" "c" "a" "a"
```

---

###### Benchmark

```r
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE, NA), 1e7, TRUE), 1e5, 1e2))

# A data.frame: 100,000 × 100
#     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5 ...
# 1 TRUE  TRUE    NA FALSE FALSE ...
# 2   NA  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE    NA ...
# 3   NA FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE ...
# 4   NA FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE ...
# 5   NA FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE ...

library(microbenchmark)

bm <- microbenchmark(
  Darren = {
    x1 <- names(df)[(which(t(df)) - 1) %% ncol(df) + 1]
  }, Clemsang = {
    x2 <- names(df)[which(t(df) == TRUE, arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]]
  })

all(x1 == x2)
# [1] TRUE

bm
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    Darren 140.5595 153.3333 163.7934 159.4783 167.5418 284.4146   100
#  Clemsang 219.7802 242.6169 254.9226 250.8673 264.0462 356.9299   100
```